# How to redirect the standard output from Sicstus4 to a Java component using Jasper?

Tags: java, sicstus-prolog

I'm using a library called Jasper to link my Java application to the Sicstus4 software. This is working smoothly but when I make a query to it I need to grab the output in order to show it in a JTextArea. Right now the Sicstus software prints the output to the console, how can I grab it?

Thank you in advance! Joshua.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know anything about Sicstus4, but if you're calling it from Java, there are examples [here](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest3/html/sicstus/Calling-Prolog-from-Java.html#Calling-Prolog-from-Java). It looks like you're supposed to get the output from the Map you pass in when you create the query.

Comment: Hi. Actually, I am retrieving the solutions from the map. What I need is to grab the output to the console. For a particular query it doesn't return anything in the map, but it does print an output in the console, that's the one I need to grab. Thank you, let me know if you have any further ideas, Joshua.